# How to handle and defuse a possible conflict professionally?

Tags: discussion, users, community

Surprisingly, I did not find any question which handles the situation
when an argument between two or more people turns into a quarrel,
and the people involved have the inkling that it will not solve
itself, but is in real danger of turning ugly. I currently have this
inkling.

*I am not concerned about serial downvoting, edit wars or other technical aspects.
This is about the effect the conflict has on the involved persons and
the surrounding community.*

The community where I have this possible conflict already had a
precedent. Two very high reputation users (> 20k) turned hostile a long time ago
and, while it is currently dormant, it did severe damage because it invited
taking sides and caused endless discussions. New users who did not know of the conflict were taken by surprise when harmless questions triggered
another round of hostility. There was banning on both sides.

Being a witness of the whole thing, I can assure you that it should not be
taken lightly and that it has *no technical solution*. The community
suffers.

The first option is be silent. For me we are beyond this part; it does not
work and I have the inkling that it reinforces hostility.

**Question:

Given the general case, how should people resolve their conflicts
professionally here in Stack Overflow and in Stack Exchange and, if
necessary, reinstate boundaries?**

One big problem here: The people do not see each other. As such you do not have
the whole spectra of non-verbal cues which help immensely to understand the situation.

Some posted a question of the specific conflict on the meta site. This often invites denial because the person feels attacked. People are invited to take a side (but, oh wonder, are often disinclined to follow and join the quarrel). Much, much drama. If confronted with much opposition, people may quit.

Chat is another option. The problem here is that people who know both are often not there which often leads to the situation that one or both sides are sniping with innocous hot-button words for the other side to provoke a reaction. (It leads to banning.)

What I miss is a "discussion room" where both participants can talk privately (only > 10k reputation can see the discussion) under mediation and if they cannot settle the quarrel, they can at least establish bounds ("We will not comment on the opponents answers and we will abstain from talking to each other"). Both hold their promises under threat of immediate expulsion from Stack Exchange.

Comment: A duel! Weapons: mackerel. Distance: three paces.

Comment: this question might also fit on Community Building

Comment: @KateGregory Oops, is that site new ?

Comment: newish, and could do with good questions :-). Not saying it doesn't belong here, it's fine here. More of a favour for CB than anything else

Answer (score 6):

**How to handle it professionally?**

As you said already, if both are professionals, they should either talk it out or just leave it and keep out of future discussions. A private chat room is the best option to clear out some confusions, but it needs both users to be constructive. Maybe a moderator could hang in to keep the process constructive, but I am not really sure if that is what moderators are for (maybe in a smaller community a moderator can bring up the time and is willing to invest into this to keep two appreciated community members).

The fact that both have been suspended shows that moderators are already on top of it, which is good. Eventually this may lead to one or both members to leave, which we want to prevent obviously, but we just want professional users. If either of them can't bring it up to be professional, it might benefit the community if they just leave. Else it might be destructive for the community.

Comment: If retaining only professional users is the goal: The problem is that it looks essentially random who really is leaving if the conflict escalates: The one who simply cannot stand it anymore, not necessarily the one acting unprofessional. You can see this pattern in other online communities like Wikipedia, tenacity and thick skin normally wins.

Comment: But we have moderators that will hopefully suspend the offending user before the other leaves.

Comment: On what factual basis does he suspend ? See, the moderator needs to know and judge the reason and be able to defend the suspension before other moderators. The moderator is caught between two stools, a very uncomfortable position. And both parties are often carefully enough to avoid smoking-gun insults, you see well-hidden venom between them which does not allow a clear-cut moderator decision. Worst of all, it stews normally for a while until mod invention becomes necessary. What I would like is a formal procedure which allows to take a shortcut to solve a situation long before escalation.